# Keep product id same from csv import products

Tags: bigcommerce, stencils

I want a solution from your idea I want to keep product id same which one I have listed into my product CSV. As I know when we import the products the products id field should be ignored, but I want to use the id from my list in CSV I do not want bigcommerce to generate the new id for products

Please check the Screenshot:

[image: index]

I want to keep these id's for my products remains the same

Is there any solutions, please

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to use your own `product_id`. They are automatically generated and assigned by the platform. If you need to keep track of them in a certain way, you can use [Product Metafields](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/#/reference/catalog/product-metafields). They allow you to create a key and namespace on each product for use in your system. They are only available via API.

Comment: I know but somehow a possible way

Comment: At this time BigCommerce does not offer a way to override the product id.